# Product rule: why not $δ_{xy}=xδ_y+yδ_x+δ_xδ_y$?

Tags: calculus, math-history

I'm reading V.I. Arnold's *Huygens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke* and he gives this diagram as part of his discussion of the derivation of the product rule, and I can't see what's wrong with it, except that it seems to give a different version of the product rule than the generally accepted one.

[image: Fig.9 of V.I. Arnold's *Huygens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke*, p.49, https://archive.org/details/huygensbarrownew0000arno/page/46]

Comment: Do you agree that the equality holds between two different ways to compute the area ?

Comment: @Jean Marie You mean do I agree that $xδ_y+yδ_x=xδ_y+yδ_x+δ_xδ_y$? If $δ_xδ_y$ is negligible then yes, the equality clearly holds. The negligibility of higher-order infinitessimals was the idea I hadn't considered when I posted the question.

Comment: A point is nothing compared to a line.

Answer (score 7):

Since $dx$ and $dy$ are infinitesimal, their product $dxdy$ is a second order infinitesimal and so can be ignored.

Of course that's not a rigorous argument - Newton didn't need one. It can be made rigorous when preceded by proper definitions.